# IIS Access Violation with WCF to connect MQSeries

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, ibm-mq

I am using the amqmdnet.dll to connect to an MQSeries Queue.

I am able to put and get messages to and from the queue in a console application, everything is OK in this case.

However I am developing a WCF and in the WCF when creating the MQQueueManeger (this line of code:

```
MQQueueManager qm = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channel, connName);
```

) I get this error:

`iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'`.

Why everything goes well with a console application and not with an WCF?

Comment: It sounds like a permission issue.   The console app is running under your credentials, whereas IIS (by default) will run under the AppPool Identity for the app pool running the WCF service.  You'll either need to use an account with the proper credentials to run the app pool or give the App Pool Identity account the permissions it needs.

Comment: thanks for your help... how can I do to give App Poll Identity account the premisions it needs?